# bad permission for mapped region at

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get segmentation fault when I try to do this. If I use valgrind to track the errors I get the message bad permission for mapped region. What does that mean ?

```
int *p;

p = (int *) f // f is a function

*p = 0x1234;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you mean `*p = 0x1234;` instead of `*ptr`). You cannot change the address of a function because it's in read-only memory.

Answer (score 2):

All code is in memory segments marked *read (and execute) only*.